# I want to check each spid/session isolation level in SQL Server. My question is specific to READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT

Tags: sql-server-2014

How to check where all my currently running sessions's isolation level. what we set at database level is READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT. I want to make sure each session is using that to make sure something is not getting changed through application while creating session-connection to SQL Server

I have tried below query but it shows only READ COMMITTED.

```
SELECT transaction_sequence_num,
       commit_sequence_num,
       is_snapshot,
       t.session_id,
       first_snapshot_sequence_num,
       max_version_chain_traversed,
       elapsed_time_seconds,
       host_name,
       login_name,
       CASE transaction_isolation_level
           WHEN '0' THEN
               'Unspecified'
           WHEN '1' THEN
               'ReadUncomitted'
           WHEN '2' THEN
               'ReadCommitted'
           WHEN '3' THEN
               'Repeatable'
           WHEN '4' THEN
               'Serializable'
           WHEN '5' THEN
               'Snapshot'
       END AS transaction_isolation_level
FROM sys.dm_tran_active_snapshot_database_transactions t
    JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions s
        ON t.session_id = s.session_id;
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the query you posted inner joins to `dm_tran_active_snapshot_database_transactions` only sessions using row versioning will by returned.  To return sessions using the Read Commited Snapshot Isolation level (`RSCI`) and sessions with other isolation levels left join to `dm_tran_active_snapshot_database_transactions` and check for a non-match (null join column).  I wasn't sure if you needed all the columns you listed from `dm_tran_active_snapshot_database_transactions` so a condensed version is below, and any columns can be added back as needed.  The `total_elapsed_time` in `dm_exec_sessions` is in milliseconds while the `elapsed_time_seconds` from `dm_tran_active_snapshot_database_transactions`  is in seconds and this example returns the result in seconds regardless of which DMV the session originates from.  I'd also recommend always aliasing columns, especially when joins are involved.

```
SELECT 
S.session_id,
S.host_name,
S.login_name,
--divide milliseconds in total_elapsed_time by 1000 
--to get time in seconds if session not using Read Committed SnapShot
COALESCE(T.elapsed_time_seconds, (S.total_elapsed_time / 1000.0)) as TimeElapsedInSeconds,
S.transaction_isolation_level,
CASE WHEN T.session_id is not null then 'ReadCommittedSnapShot' ELSE
CASE S.transaction_isolation_level
WHEN 0 THEN 'Unspecified'
WHEN 1 THEN 'ReadUncomitted'
WHEN 2 THEN 'ReadCommitted'
WHEN 3 THEN 'Repeatable'
WHEN 4 THEN 'Serializable'
WHEN 5 THEN 'Snapshot' END
END as transaction_isolation_level
FROM SYS.DM_EXEC_SESSIONS S
LEFT JOIN SYS.DM_TRAN_ACTIVE_SNAPSHOT_DATABASE_TRANSACTIONS T on S.session_id = T.session_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I think this may work
SELECT transaction_sequence_num,
       commit_sequence_num,
       is_snapshot,
       t.session_id,
       first_snapshot_sequence_num,
       max_version_chain_traversed,
       elapsed_time_seconds,
       host_name,
       login_name,
       CASE transaction_isolation_level
           WHEN '0' THEN
               'Unspecified'
           WHEN '1' THEN
               'ReadUncomitted'
           WHEN '2' THEN
               CASE
                   WHEN
                   (
                       SELECT [is_read_committed_snapshot_on]
                       FROM sys.databases
                       WHERE [database_id] = s.[database_id]
                   ) = 1 THEN
                       'ReadCommittedSnapShot'
                   ELSE
                       'ReadCommitted'
               END
           WHEN '3' THEN
               'Repeatable'
           WHEN '4' THEN
               'Serializable'
           WHEN '5' THEN
               'Snapshot'
       END AS transaction_isolation_level
FROM sys.dm_tran_active_snapshot_database_transactions t
    JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions s
        ON t.session_id = s.session_id;
```